# Extending HDD in Ubuntu 18 Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I am running ubuntu server 18 in hyper-v, I need to extend HDD. When i use fdisk -l I see that /dev/sda2/ have 1TB:

```
  Disk /dev/sda: 1 TiB, 1105954078720 bytes, 2160066560 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
  Disklabel type: gpt
  Disk identifier: 8F74C1DF-DF9B-4FD7-AD20-87F1D8A8F989

  Device     Start        End    Sectors Size Type
 /dev/sda1   2048       4095       2048   1M BIOS boot
 /dev/sda2   4096 2160066526 2160062431   1T Linux filesystem
```

when i use df -h i see that /dev/sda2 have only 125G:

```
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  udev            419M     0  419M   0% /dev
 tmpfs            90M  972K   89M   2% /run
 /dev/sda2       125G   11G  108G   9% /
 tmpfs           449M     0  449M   0% /dev/shm
 tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
 tmpfs           449M     0  449M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
 /dev/loop0       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6350
 /dev/loop1       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/6964
/dev/loop2       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/docker/384
/dev/loop3       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/docker/372
/dev/loop4       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/docker/381
/dev/loop5       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6818
tmpfs            90M     0   90M   0% /run/user/1000
```

What should I do, when I want to use full disk capacity? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like the actual partition us larger then what the filesystem thinks. This is unusual but can happen when you bitcopy the contents if a block device to a larger one.

Before doing disk operations its a good idea to back up your data as there is  small chance things will go seriously wrong. Once you have backed up simply issue a command to grow the filesystem. This can usually be done online (but you can't shrink online). Assuming its on ext filesystem the command is something like resize2fs /dev/sda2 or resize4fs /dev/sda2.dependong on distro. If its not an ext filesystem there is likely an equivalent command.

Comment: Thank you very much sudo resize2fs /dev/sda2 helped me!